# How to get YouTube video to re-size for mobile when in a DIV

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

I have a YouTube video in a DIV that won't seem to re-size to fit a mobile screen's browser window.

The goal is to have 3 sections on a desktop computer:
YouTube Video (section 1) SPACING (section 2) Text (section 3) (in a line from left to right)

On a mobile device, the goal is to have:
YouTube Video, fit to screen width (section 1)
SPACING (section 2) (I wish this wasn't here... but it's needed so there's space between the video and the text on a desktop computer)
Text (section 3)
(going down the page from top to bottom)

Here's the relevant code.  Please note: I don't code for a living, which is why I could really use some help with this.  Thank you!

```
<style type="text/css"><!--
.section1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 450px;
background-color:white;
}
.section2 { 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
width: 10px;
background-color:white;
}
.section3 { 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 10px double #191919;
    padding: .600em;
    width: 450px;
background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
--></style>

<center>
<div class="section1"><iframe width="400" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/auukuYuizq4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>

<div class="section2"> </div>
<div class="section3">Text here</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Why not use padding instead of an empty div or section

Comment: Good point.  Also, if you have any thoughts on my below comment to another's answer, please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [grid](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp) or [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.section1 {
  background-color: white;
}

.section2 {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

.section3 {
  border: 10px double #191919;
  padding: .600em;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section1">
    <iframe width="400" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/auukuYuizq4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
  </div>
  <div class="section3">
    Text here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  However, for some reason, it doesn't show the video when I do this.  In the "Run code snippet" it works fine.  However, it doesn't work on my site.  I'm running it on Shopify's platform, so I don't know if there's some reason it doesn't work there.  However, with the code I originally submitted, it did show up.  It's just that it didn't re-size appropriately.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Side note: I tried adding <iframe width="400" height="225" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/auukuYuizq4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe> below the area we've been discussing.  It automatically fit the video to full screen rather than a width of 400.  I'm thinking this must have something to do with pre-set parameters on the Shopify theme I'm using?